# Adding 4 byte values causes Overflow Exception

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

The following code raises a System.OverflowException

```
    Dim b1 As Byte = 13
    Dim b2 As Byte = 26
    Dim b3 As Byte = 125
    Dim b4 As Byte = 225

    Dim i As Integer = (b1 + b2 + b3 + b4) \ 2
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: 389 divided by 2 is 194.5, which is NOT an integer.

Comment: @N0Alias : He's using [integer division](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/integer-division-operator), besides even if he weren't it would still be implicitly converted to an Integer.

Comment: Becauase `(b1 + b2 + b3 + b4) ` is  treated as byte and evaluated from left to right. Everything goes ok with `b1 + b2 + b3` which is still byte. When you add `b4` is when the overflow occurs. About [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/operator-precedence)

Comment: @EmilioCeroleni : Actually even the integer division (`\ 2`) seems to be treated as `Byte`. When I tested it and assigned the result to a variable with inferred type it resulted in a `System.Byte`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value(s) doesn't get converted into an `Integer` until you assign it to the variable. This means that up until, and including, the `\ 2` part everything is still of type `Byte`.

To make this work you've got to convert at least the first variable into an `Integer`, so that additional numbers can be added to it and go beyond 255.

```
Dim i As Integer = (CType(b1, Integer) + b2 + b3 + b4) \ 2
```

**Online test:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lxmx2S

---

Be aware that since this respects the order of mathematical operations, you must convert all the instances of too small types that are calculated before the others. For instance if you changed your operation to this:

```
Dim i As Integer = (CType(b1, Integer) + b2 * b3 + b4) \ 2
```

It would also throw an error because `b2 * b3` is calculated *before* `b1 + b2`, and thus you would have to change it to:

```
Dim i As Integer = (CType(b1, Integer) + CType(b2, Integer) * b3 + b4) \ 2
```

Comment: Thanks, and is there a way that would not make my code look like some maniac typed it? :-)

Comment: @tmighty : You calling me a maniac? D: -- Well, either convert the variables beforehand (i.e. `Dim n1 As Integer = b1` and so on...) or use Visual Basic's built-in `CInt()` function: `Dim i As Integer = (CInt(b1) + b2 * b3 + b4) \ 2`

Comment: @tmighty : There's also the .NET function `Convert.ToInt32()`, which works in C# and other .NET languages as well: `Dim i As Integer = (Convert.ToInt32(b1) + b2 * b3 + b4) \ 2`

Comment: I think that converting only the two first bytes and not the other ones looks strange. Why don't you (have to) do it for all bytes?

Comment: @tmighty : The reason you don't _have_ to convert them all is because the compiler will run everything from left to right (or according to the order of mathematical operations). It will always keep adding to the _**first number**_ of the sum.

Comment: @tmighty : For instance, if you to the integer `i = 10` added the bytes `b1 = 2, b2 = 5, b3 = 3`, looking like this: `i + b1 + b2 + b3`, the compiler would do the following: **1)** `i(10) + b1(2) + b2(5) + b3(3)` **2)** `i(12) + b2(5) + b3(3)` **3)** `i(17) + b3(3)` **4)** `i(20)` -- As you see all the bytes were added one-by-one, in order, to the already existing first number of the sequence (the integer).

Comment: @tmighty : No problem, glad I could help! -- Maybe this just confuses things for you, but integers are really just arrays of four (4) bytes. I made a code example showing what happens "under the hood". Pay attention to the _output_ of this rather than the code itself; it shows what really happens when you add a byte (right) to an integer (left), and also what happens when the integer goes beyond 255. The integer starts at 0 (represented as `{0, 0, 0, 0}` in byte array form). Again, this _**may be**_ confusing: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9MnMt9